# Select remote on Git status

Tags: git

I can use `git status` to tell me if I'm ahead or behind the remote:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'bean/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Which is fine for parsing:

```
needs_push = "Your branch is ahead" in std.out
needs_pull = "Your branch is behind" in std.out
```

However, when working with multiple remotes things fall down, since `git status` only shows the result for one remote (`bean` in the example above) and takes no parameters to select the remote.

**Is there any way I to specify the remote to show details for?**
i.e. given two remotes, does my local repository/branch need pushing and/or pulling, and if so, which? By "needs pulling" I mean that the remote contains commits I've not got, and by "needs pushing" I mean that I've got commits the remote hasn't got. (i.e. assume a linear workflow with nothing esoteric.)

If I could use a URL rather than a name that would be even better, but as far as I'm aware git is only able to describe remotes after calling `git remote update`.

Comment: I don't completely understand your requirement, because `git status` shows the status of a given _branch_.  That a single branch has only one remote is an afterthought in my mind.  Can you clarify what you want to do here?

Comment: You have `git log <branch>...<someremote/branch1>` or `git diff <branch>..<someremote/branch1>` that show you even more information than `git status` in the way you mentioned.

Comment: I want to know if I should pull and/or push to/from each of my two remotes (without actually pulling or pushing)

Comment: "Should" pull or push is a concept you created. `git-status` only shows the commits difference between your branch and its tracking branch. If that means you should pull or push, it's up to you. If you need to see the commits between your branch and some branch not tracked, you need to either set it as a tracking branch or use `git-log`, `git-diff` or other commands.

Comment: You answered my question @SamirAguiar, e.g. `git log alpha/master | grep "commit" | head` and `git log beta/master | grep "commit" | head` give what I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: @cz glad I could help :) Still, I think you should check the docs about refspecs and try to use them with `git-log`, that may be even more complete.

Comment: *Useless use of grep* detected.

Comment: @SamirAguiar thanks to your comment I found out about `git rev-list --count` and added the much better **Approach A** to my answer. As a bonus it doesn't need any `grep`-ing

Comment: @AnimiVulpis no problem, I should have said `gitrevisions` as you did in your answer since that's what I meant, but at least it worked.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer or if you still have a problem help us to help you

Answer (score 2):

### Approach A

Maybe even easier (depending on what you want to achieve):

- [`$ git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#git-rev-list---count)`--count <branch-name>..<remote>/<remote-branch-name>`

Will output the number of commits the first branch is behind the remote branch

- [`$ git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#git-rev-list---count)`--count <remote>/<remote-branch-name>..<branch-name>`

Will output the number of commits the first branch is ahead the remote branch

With this command you can list all sorts of things you might want to know. But you need to understand [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) first.

```
$ git rev-list --count <some git revision specification>
```

---

### Approach B

Depending of what exactly you are going to do with this information the following might come in handy:

- [`$ git branch -u <upstream>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---set-upstream-toltupstreamgt)`# short for --set-upsteam-to=<upstream>`
  to set the upstream of the current branch
- [`$ git status --porcelain=v2 --branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_branch_headers) to get a very easily parsable output containing information about the *upstream* relation

The output would look for example like this:

```
# branch.oid <hash>
# branch.head example-branch
# branch.upstream origin/example-branch-developer-1
# branch.ab +0 -1
```

The last line being the most interesting for you with the following format:

> `# branch.ab +<ahead> -<behind>`

Answer (score 0):

> If I could use a URL rather than a name that would be even better, but as far as I'm aware git is only able to describe remotes after calling `git remote update`.

That's correct, if a bit imprecise.  What's happening "under the hood" here is that once you have done `git fetch`—`git remote update` just runs `git fetch`, more or less, to various remotes, and you can do this from `git fetch` itself, so use whichever command you prefer, they basically do the same thing here—*your* Git now has, in your repository, every commit that *their* Git has; and *your* Git has updated your *remote-tracking branch names* such as `origin/master` and `bean/master` and whatever additional remotes you have.

Hence, now that you have what they have *and more* (if there is anything more anyway), you can now figure out whether any given branch-name that you have points to:

- the same commit as some remote-tracking branch name;
- an *earlier* commit on the same chain of commits;
- a *later* commit on the same chain of commits; or
- a *completely unrelated* commit.

(The last case is unlikely, but should be mentioned for completeness.)

#### Chains of commits: the commit graph

These *chains of commits* are those formed by the commit graph or DAG:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master
```

represents a very simple repository with just three commits.  We say that the *name* `master` "points to" commit `C`, because `master` contains the big ugly hash ID that is the "true name" of commit `C`.  Meanwhile commit `C` contains the hash ID for commit `B`, so `C` points to `B`; and similarly, `B` points to `A`.  `B` is `C`'s parent, and `A` is `B`'s parent.

Since `A` was the very first commit, there is no parent commit ID it can have; so it has none.  This makes it a *root commit*, and it points nowhere, which means `git log` can stop printing things.  We—or `git log`—will start with the name `master` and view commit `C`, then follow `C`'s arrow back to `B` and view `B`.  Then it will follow the backwards arrow to `A` and view `A`, and now it's out of things to follow and is done.

When you `git fetch` a new commit `D` that has `C` as its parent, we get the slightly more complicated picture:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- bean/master
```

It's easy to see from this drawing that `bean/master` is "one commit ahead" of `master`.  But internally, all Git arrows work backwards, so in fact, Git has to start from `bean/master` and work *back*, and when it finds commit `C` which is `master`, that's when we know that `master` is one behind `bean/master`.

As [AnimiVulpis answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829289/1256452) (upvoted), you can get `git rev-list` to *count* commits for you, using `--count`.  Normally it just lists the commit hashes.  It's just like `git log`: it starts at the commit you tell it to start at, and follows the internal "arrows" backwards from one commit to another.  If you give it a *stopping* point, it stops when it reaches a commit that is the stopping-point or—this part is a bit tricky—is *reachable from* the stopping point.

Let's draw a slightly more complicated picture, where you've made one new commit on your `master`—we'll call this `E`—and brought in `D` from `bean` to make `bean/master` point to it:

```
        E   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- bean/master
```

Now `master` is one commit ahead of `bean/master`, and `bean/master` is one commit ahead of `master`, *at the same time*.  This is because if we start from `master` and work backwards, we find one commit that we cannot reach by starting at `bean/master` and working backwards.  The same is true if we start the other way around.

Hence, we need *two* `git rev-list` commands.  We would run one with `master ^bean/master` aka `bean/master..master`: start with `master`, stop when reaching commit `C` because it's reachable from `bean/master`.  That counts commit `E` on `master`, and stops.  The other, we will use `bean/master ^master` aka `master..bean/master`: start with `bean/master`, and stop when reaching commit `C` because it's reachable from `master`.

This *reachability* concept is one of the key graph-theory bits that makes Git work.  A good way to visualize it is to imagine coloring each commit temporarily, as with a highlighter pen: we color some commits red as "stop" and others green as "go", and red tends to override green, if we're doing both colors "at the same time".  The `X ^Y` notation means *use green starting from `X` and red starting from `Y`*.  The `Y..X` notation is just shorthand for the same thing.

#### Symmetric difference makes this a bit easier

As it turns out, Git has a special notation, `X...Y` (three dots instead of two), that denotes a *symmetric difference*: color commits green if reachable from *only one* of the starting points, but red if reachable from both.  In this graph, `bean/master...master` would select commit `E`—reachable from `master` but not `bean/master`—*and* commit `D`, but would reject commits `C` and earlier.

That doesn't necessarily seem all that useful here, until you find that `git rev-list` has a `--left-right` option as well.  When using this option with the symmetric difference three-dot syntax, Git will note which commits came from the "left name" (`bean/master`) and which came from the "right name" (`master`).  Normally, when `git rev-list` is spitting out commit hash IDs, it uses `<` and `>` to mark these.  But if you add `--count`, Git just counts them as usual, then prints *two* numbers:

```
git rev-list --count bean/master...master
```

The number on the left is the number of commits reachable from `bean/master` but not from `master`, and the number on the right is the number of commits reachable from `master` but not from `bean/master`.

And—aha!—these are exactly the counts that `git status` prints for "behind" and "ahead".  (Swap the names to get them in the other order, if you prefer.)

#### The caveat: unrelated branches

You can, if you use unrelated repositories or `git checkout --orphan`, create a repository with disjoint subgraphs within it:

```
A--B--C   <-- master

D--E   <-- unrelated/master
```

The symmetric difference notation will, in this case, list or count all the commits on both branches, since all it does is list or count commits reachable from either name but not from both.  Since the parent chains never come together, *no* commit is reachable from both.

You can detect this situation if you really need to—when it occurs there is no *merge base* between the two names—but it generally should not happen in the first place.  Note that having multiple roots is not a guarantee, since we can deliberately merge unrelated histories:

```
A--B
    \
     E--F   <-- branch
    /
C--D
```

and we can even have a fork after the merge:

```
A--B      G   <-- br1
    \    /
     E--F
    /    \
C--D      H--I   <-- br2
```

but these branches *do* have a merge base commit (it's commit `F`, which is obvious from the graph).