# How do I do git status upstream?

Tags: git, upstream-branch

In my forked repository I have set up a `remote origin` and `remote upstream` (the original repo).

`git status` *compare to origin*.
How do I *compare to `upstream`*?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For git status to compare the current branch to a different remote, you would need to set that remote for said branch

```
git config branch.<mybranch>.remote upstream
```

Then try `git status` again (possibly [after a `git remote update`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427/6309)).

See more at "[Select remote on Git status](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46828384/6309)".

Comment: thank you! Then I have to bring remote back to origin with the same (but reversed) command (am I wrong?). Is there any single command option? Like `git status upstream master`?

Comment: @aerijman You are not wrong and can reverse the config easily enough.

Comment: @aerijman I don't remember a simple command for that: as illustrated with https://stackoverflow.com/q/23455842/6309, a config change is generally needed.